# Installing flutter on Mac iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, macos, installation, air

Unfortunately, I couldn’t install flutter on my MacBook Air. Every time I install flutter SDK I see some documents but none of them leads to extract flutter? I can’t find the folder flutter_macOS?

Comment: You should install using Git. I installed flutter using git clone on my Macbook Pro.

Comment: I did install Xcode which it should include git but still I can’t find the zip document so I can extract?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ok! I’ll provide more details. I visit flutter website and then I choose Mac OS install then I scroll down and to Get the Flutter SDK and then I press on the blue area where it says flutter_macos_2.10.2-stable.zip after the download is finished I open the Flutter document and I see many documents and files and I click on each one but none of them extracts the Flutter. I mean none of them it says  flutter_macos_2.10.2-stable.zip?? Do you think Flutter is installed already in my device?? In case yes, so what is the next step??

Answer (score 0):

Do you have install flutter SDK follow by official document?

[https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos]

Document need required 2 steps,

Step1: download Flutter SDK and extract zip.

Step 2: set **Path** for ternimal

Notes: *You need set path Flutter SDK if the IDE need to required (Ex: Android Studio)*

I hope helpfully for you

Comment: The problem is I can’t find the Flutter SDK and extract zip document in the download area!!

Comment: Do you change default download arena in the browser? If you are, please go to new download folder, Or you check on download history to locate your SDK download.